# Entering SUMIFS formula into table with VBA triggers run time error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I've had a scroll through most of the SUMIFS questions here and they all seem to be variations of double quote problems, as opposed to what I'm getting.

I'm trying to insert sumifs into a table which is triggering runtime error 1004.  The sum range, and the three criteria ranges are all in a different table (on a different tab, though that shouldn't make a difference), and the three criteria are all in the table where the formula is being entered.  The first critera is the row header, the other two are other cells in the same row.  Within the code, the table where the criteria are, and the formula is being entered is in a ListObject variable (summary_table) and the sum and criteria ranges are in a different ListObject variable (data_table)

Code is as follows:

```
    For i = 5 To summary_table.ListColumns.Count - 1
        summary_table.ListColumns(i).DataBodyRange.Formula = _
            "=SUMIFS(data_table[Amount],data_table[FOCUS GLs],summary_table[[#Headers],[" & _
            summary_table.HeaderRowRange(i).Value & "]],data_table[Employee Number]," & _
            "[@[Position Number]],data_table[Posting Date],[@[Posting Date]]"
    Next i
```

Basically, just looping through the fifth column through to second last and inserting this sumifs formula in.  This is then within a larger loop that goes through 40 or so entities. The summary_table is a listObject variable pass to this particular sub.

If I put a debug.print statement in to look at the actual formula string that is being produced, and copy that into the table, the formula works fine.

If I built a sub-routine that puts the sum range and the three criteria ranges into range variables, and the three criteria into three long variables, then loop through each range in each listColumn.DataBodyRange and enter in the result of calling Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(sum_range, crit_range1, crit1 etc...), that will populate the cells with the correct value.

However, this takes 10-20 second per entity for which this is being done, adding 7-15 minutes to the running time. If the formula in the code block worked, it should only be a few milliseconds.  Additionally, if someone updates the data table (which is unlikely, but possible), the lack of a formula means the summary table will no longer hold the correct value.

I cannot for the life of me work out why it is not working and would appreciate any comments, observations, thoughts or general abuse.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you apply a few basics. That will make your formula easier to read. Once it's easier to read I would attempt to do so. But if it were easier to read you probably wouldn't need my help. So, let's apply basics.

A *ListObject* as a `Range`, `ListRows` and `ListColumns`. It also has *Header* and *Total* rows which are included in the `Range`.

A *ListObject's* `DataBodyRange` excludes the headers and totals. It's nothing but a named range. In fact, the name for it is set up by Excel to be the same as the table's. Since it's a range it has rows and columns which you can address by their range (`DataBodyRange`) or sheet coordinates.

Therefore one wouldn't use *ListRows* or *ListColumns* to address *DataBodyRange* rows and columns. Your code would become a lot simpler if you were to use `With summary_table.DataBodyRange` to start the show off.

A SUMIFS function has these arguments:-

```
= SUMIFS(SumRng, Crit1_Rng, Crit1, Crit2_Rng, Crit2, etc)
```

Therefore, once you hit a problem - and a problem you did hit - you should resolve all arguments. Then your code would look somewhat like this:-

```
Dim Formla      As String
Dim SumRng      As Range
Dim Crit1_Rng   As Range
Dim Crit1       As Variant
Dim Crit2_Rng   As Range
Dim Crit2       As Variant

Formla = "=SUMIFS(" & SumRng.Address & _
                "," & Crit1_Rng.Address & "," & Crit1 & _
                "," & Crit2_Rng.Address & "," & Crit2 & ")"
```

True, your code looks a lot more compact and uses fewer characters but it also brought you to this forum. `Set SumRng = data_table[Amount]` allows you to check `Debug.Print SumRng.Address`, a luxury you have denied yourself by design. And please don't believe that your code would run faster because it doesn't need to assign the range to a variable. It will have to do that whether you instruct or not.

Now all that remains is to assign the formula. You suggest `summary_table.ListColumns(i).DataBodyRange.Formla`. But wouldn't that assign the same formula to every cell in the DataBodyRange? If you want to assign the formula to all cells in one column your syntax should look somewhat like this:-

```
summary_table.DataBodyRange.Columns(i).Formula = Formla
```

Of course, this doesn't address the question of absolute and relative referencing. But in the logically structured approach that I have recommended above you would solve that when you assign the ranges, perhaps using `Address(0, 0)` in place of the naked `Address` I showed above, setting the formula for a single cell and then copying that cell to the rest of the column. But you can also use structural referencing, perhaps by using string variables in place of the ranges I showed above. Once the toys are all laid out you can start playing with them.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't solve the problem.  While I agree your suggestion makes the code somewhat neater, the moment I assign the formula to a string variable, and set any range variable's .formula parameter to that formula string, I get the error. The only way to avoid it is to use the application.worksheetfunction to calculate the sumifs formula in VBA, then take that result and set the range.value variable to that value.  That means iterating over the entire databodyrange for each listcolumn, and that adds massive amount of runtime.

Comment: I didn't promise to solve the problem, only to make it manageable, meaning it shifts to where you can deal with it. If you need help with that, please publish your revised code. I would also ask to show the `Formla` string created by the revised code. However, your new approach to the use of that formula, i.e. write the results to the sheet instead of the formula, makes much better sense. Use `Cells(R, C).Value = Application.Evaluate(Formla)` where the specified cell can be from the sheet or DataBodyRange. If you want it faster, write the results to an array and paste the array when done.

Comment: Examine your formula for proper referencing. Each range must be fully qualified, meaning include the sheet name. You can use `Sheet1.Evaluate` instead of `Application.Evaluate` to specify the default sheet but since your formula references several sheets that can't be a solution for all occasions.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you playing along at home (and I suspect it's only me, but there's a useful lesson in this anyway), I finally found the answer to the problem, and it's as stupid a minor detail as is always the case.  I decided that VBA didn't like SUMIFS formulas split across two tables on two different sheets, so decided to change it to cell references. (For the record, VBA is fine with formulae across multiple tables on multiple sheets, but it at least led me down the right path).

Now, the default A1 reference style is a thing of beauty when working directly in the Excel spreadsheet, but it's disgusting to code with (getting the .address variable and splitting on $ is just unnecessary code - great if you're being paid by line of code, but just nasty to work with and worse to maintain).  So I used R1C1 reference style.  Still wouldn't work in the VBA code, but if I debug.printed the formula out and copied and pasted, it was fine.  But, R1C1 formulae tend to be much shorter, so I could compare the debug.print text, copy and paste it just under where I had the formula I'd built in Excel as a comment straight under each other on a single line, and lo and behold:

'=SUMIFS(Data!R2C17:R777C17,Data!R2C1:R777C1,R1C,Data!R2C13:R777C13,RC1,Data!R2C16:R777C16,RC4)'    '=SUMIFS(Data!R2C17:R777C17,Data!R2C1:R777C1,R1C,Data!R2C13:R777C13,RC1,Data!R2C16:R777C16,RC4

"Close your (expletive deleted) brackets, Yianni!!!"

And of course, Excel somewhere around the 07 release decided that if a simple, non nested, single bracket formula was missing the last bracket, it would just add it when you hit enter, so pasting the incorrect formula in Excel worked because it corrected it for me...

So, the takeout from this is something I should have known all along - R1C1 reference style is always the answer in VBA if at all possible, it's just this particular case needs table reference formulae instead.